# Encontrar el ultimo elemento del array

Tags: c++

Buenas noches gente,
Tengo un problema raro. Cree una función para dar con el ultimo elemento de un array, y me da de más, no entiendo por que

```
int ultimo_elem (int x[]){
int contador = 0;
while (x[contador]){
    contador += 1;
}
return contador;
}
```

Y usando el main así:

```
int main (){
int array[] = {23, 43, 35, 38, 67, 12, 76, 10, 34, 8};

cout << ultimo_elem (array) << endl;
}
```

Desde ya gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Tu planteamiento es erróneo. Tu código no busca el último elemento del *arreglo*, busca **el primer elemento que sea `0`**, que no es ni mucho menos lo mismo.

En C++, un *arreglo* no es mas que una sucesión de datos en la memoria. No lleva *aclopada* ninguna información sobre su tamaño, ni ninguna marca de *fin de arreglo* ni nada parecido. No es mas que un grupo de datos, mezclado con todos los demás datos que se encuentren en la memoria del equipo.

Por eso tu código falla. Busca un `0`, y seguramente lo encontrará, pero no hay forma de saber exactamente **donde** lo va a encontrar. Desde luego, no hay ninguno en los valores de tu *arreglo*.

Tienes que cambiar tu planteamiento:

- Puedes llamar a tu función con un argumento que indique el tamaño.

En ese caso, tienes que cambiar el como la llamas y lo que hace la función:

```
int ultimo_elem (int x[], size_t size ) {
  return ( size / sizeof( x[0] ) ) - 1;
}

cout << ultimo_elem( array, sizeof( array ) ) << endl;
```

- Puedes indicar un tamaño exacto en el *arreglo* que esperas.

Pero entonces, no podrás usar la función con *arreglos* de otros tamaños:

```
int ultimo_elem (int x[10]){ return 9; }

cout << ultimo_elem( array ) << endl;
```

- Puedes poner tu mismo una *marca* en el último valor del arreglo.

Es lo que menos cambios necesita:

```
int array[] = { 23, 43, 35, 38, 67, 12, 76, 10, 34, 8, 0 };
```

- Puedes hacer una o función *plantilla* que te valga para distintos tamaños.

Creo aun es pronto para que te plantees esta opción :-)

Comment: Sisi, entiendo lo que me decis. Muchas gracias por las respuestas :D

Answer (score 3):

Acá abajo pongo una forma "genérica", de una función que recibe una referencia a un array y devuelve su último elemento. Creo que es una forma común de hacerlo en C++ moderno:

```
template <typename T, size_t N> 
T ultimo_elem(T(&a)[N])
{
    return a[N - 1];
}
```

Si sólo necesitas conocer la posición del último elemento:

```
template <typename T, size_t N> 
size_t ultimo_elem(T(&a)[N])
{
    return N - 1;
}
```

Comment: Muchas graciaas :D

Comment: Si alguna de estas respuestas es correcta, deberías marcarla como tal y así agradecerle por tomarse un poco de su tiempo y dedicarlo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

recuerda que para obtener el objeto de un array inicia en la posición 0, esto quiere decir que si tu array es var arr = {1} y quieres obtener el valor tienes que accesar a tu posición 0 es decir arr[0]

si quieres obtener el ultimo valor de tu array seria 
arr[arr.count-1];

saludos

Comment: ¿ `var` ? ¿ `arr.count` ? ¿ Eso que es, _Javascript_ ? ¿ C# ?

Answer (score -2):

Aquí tienes el programa funcionando. Lo mejor y más práctico es usar una fórmula para calcular el último elemento `(largo / sizeof(arreglo[0]) ) - 1;` donde `largo = sizeof(arreglo);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int ultimo_elem (int arreglo[],int largo);

int main()
{
    /*  Aquí se define el arreglo de int de tamaño de 10 elementos:                         */
    int largo;
    int arreglo[] = {23, 43, 35, 38, 67, 12, 76, 10, 34, 8};
    largo = sizeof(arreglo);
    cout << "El valor almacenado correspondiente al ultimo elemento es " << arreglo[ultimo_elem(arreglo,largo)]<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int ultimo_elem (int arreglo[],int largo){
    int ultimo=0;
    ultimo = (largo / sizeof(arreglo[0]) ) - 1; //tomar el tamaño del arreglo y lo dividirlo por el tamaño del primer elemento
    return ultimo;
}
```